# Reversing the ids

Tags: python

I am getting the change ids using the following code and then for looping...I need to reverse the ids I get in teh file change_ids.txt..I need some ideas on the best way to do this revers?please provide your thoughts.

```
with open(timedir + "/change_ids.txt", "wb") as f:
    check_call("ssh -p 29418 company.com "
        "gerrit query --commit-message --files --current-patch-set "
        "status:open project:platform/vendor/com-proprietary/code branch:master |"
        "grep refs |"
        "cut -f4 -d'/'",
            shell=True,   # need shell due to the pipes
            stdout=file)  # redirect to a file
 for line in open(timedir + "/change_ids.txt"):
#code
```

change_ids.txt contains

```
210717
210716
210715
210714
210713
```

Comment: What does `change_ids.txt` look like? Also `file` is bad choice for an identifier, as it's a Python built-in.

Comment: @Johnsyweb - I updated question on how change_ids.txt looks like

Comment: And by "I need to reverse the ids I get in teh file ", you mean that you need to process these IDs in reverse order? Then [pts's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14211206/78845) should suffice. Personally, I'd do away with the temporary file and the remote `grep`/`cut` to contain the processing.

Comment: @Johnsyweb - Yes,ids should be processed in reverse order..also how do you get away from temporary file and remote grep/cut

Answer (score 1):

This will process the lines from bottom to top:

```
for line in reversed(list(open(timedir + "/gerrit_ids.txt"))):
    ...
```